# How to join a list of tables in kdb

Tags: kdb

I'm using the below to join multiple tables

```
() uj/(a;b;c)
```

However is there a way to pass a list of tables to achieve this?

Currently if i do the below I get a type error

```
tbList:tables[]
() uj/(tbList)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uj` requires table arguments, while `tables[]` returns the names of variables in the root namespace which are tables as a list of symbols.

To get a list of tables from this you can use `value each tables[]` which will evaluate each variable name in turn and will return the evaluated tables as a list.

If `/` (over) is supplied with only a single list argument, it will take the first element to be the initial value so you don't need to supply an empty list as the initial value like so:

`uj/[value each tables[]]`

Answer (score 2):

Technically it can be achieved by passing the table names:

```
eval (uj/;enlist,`tab1`tab2`tab3)
```

but it might be more conventional to use `value` as others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
() uj/value each tbList
```

valuing a symbol, returns the value of the variable it names.

Comment: Note that calling `tables[]` directly returns a list of symbols, whereas by prepending this with `value each` we return a list of the tables themselves